# Riemannian metric conformal to another metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

> Suppose $M$ is a surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then it has the natural induced Euclidean metric, denoted by $\textbf{g}$. Suppose $\tilde{\textbf{g}}$ is another Riemannian metric on $M$, we say it is conformal to $\textbf{g}$, if the two metrics differ by a scalar function $u\colon M \to \mathbb{R}$, nameley $\tilde{\textbf{g}} = e^{2u} \textbf{g}$.

A simple question. How to derive $e^{2u}$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\tilde g = \phi g$ and both $g, \tilde g$ are Riemannian metrics, then the function $\phi$ relating them must be positive, and thus can be represented as $\phi = e^{2u}$ for $u=\frac12 \ln \phi$. We simply choose to work with the conformal factor in this form to make some computations simpler.

Comment: That's the only reason? :D Are there another placeholders instead of $e^{2u}$?

Comment: $e^{2u}$ and $\phi^2$ are the only ones I can remember seeing.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying things. :)